# Why I am getting the output of aws polly describe voice as gibrish?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am on windows 10 and have aws cli installed
aws-cli/2.0.21 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev25
Now I tried this command:

```
 aws polly describe-voices --language en-US --output table
```

The output is gibrish.[image]

Comment: It's probably due to your terminal configuration. Perhaps try it in a PowerShell window? Or, output in a different format (text, json).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the same command on power shell. The result is gibrish. But I tried output to json and it worked. Thanks. revised command was - aws polly describe-voices --language en-US --output json

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the cause is one of the following (I am not sure yet):

- A problem in the command line configuration (specifically characters supported).
- Or it is a problem from AWS itself.

Anyways you can write the command without specifying an output (table), you will get a JSON format output it is easier to deal with:

```
 aws polly describe-voices --language en-US
```

The result will be in a JSON format like this:

[image: A screenshot of the command result]